# CORS complaint on Safari 5.1.7 (windows 7)

Tags: safari, xmlhttprequest, cors

A page at http://www4.example.com that tries to an xhr connection to http://www6.example.com/
The browser sends a GET request with this header:

```
Origin: http://www4.example.com
```

The www6.example.com server sends back:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www4.example.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: ...
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Transfer-Encoding: Identity
Server: Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.6-13ubuntu3.7
```

And yet I get:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www6.example.com/myscript.php?xhr=1&t=1234333223. Origin http://www4.example.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

My code matches my understanding of the CORS standard, and works fine with Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc. so I'm going to assume this is a Safari 5.1 bug? My question is what do I need to do to work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, and watching network traffic, I think I can self-answer.

The Safari bug is that it sends an OPTIONS pre-flight request first, even though it is a GET request.

To add some extra complexity, it appears to only send this on the 2nd request. (I think this is because my 2nd request sends an extra custom header... but I couldn't actually isolate that, so I think there is something else going on as well - perhaps cache interactions?)

Sending `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` in the main response does not fix the problem: it does the OPTIONS request first, so never gets that far.

The fix I did was to put this at the very top of the PHP script:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS'){
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ".@$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Last-Event-Id, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    exit;
    }
```

Sending back "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *" did *not* work. You have to explicitly list the headers you want. I briefly experimented and it appears they are case-insensitive.

Sending back "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS" was not needed.

As an aside, Cookies *are* sent, but basic auth details are not sent (despite explicitly listing the Authorization header there). This might be a deliberate limitation of the CORS implementation, as of this version of WebKit (534.57.2), not a bug.

Comment: As per the specifications, if the request contains a header not considered as a "simple header", ie. Authorization, a preflight request is required. So, it's not a bug.